# email publisher for cruisecontrol.net

Tags: email, configuration, cruisecontrol.net

I am attempting to configure our build process so that build exceptions only get emailed to the buildmanager.

I must be doing something wrong because even though I have the groups well defined and everyone gets mailed the exception emails.

Below is a code segment showing my current structure. This emailconfig.xml file is imported into my projects. Is there something I am missing in my understanding how notificationType should be used? Thank you.

```xml
<cb:config-template xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
    <email from="$(MAIL_FROM)" mailhost="$(MAIL_HOST)" mailport="25" includeDetails="TRUE">
        <users>
            <user name="DevTeam" group="developers" address="ACDev@companyname.com"/>
            <user name="QA-OnPrem" group="QA" address="QA-OnPrem@companyname.com"/>
            <user name="BuildManagers" group="buildmaster" address="ACBuilds@companyname.com"/> 
            <user name="Some Name" group="BA" address="sname@companyname.com"/>
        </users>
        <groups>
            <group name="buildmaster">
                <notifications>
                    <notificationType>Always</notificationType>
                </notifications>
            </group>
            <group name="developers">
                <notifications>
                    <notificationType>Failed</notificationType>
                    <NotificationType>Success</NotificationType>
                    <NotificationType>Change</NotificationType>
                </notifications>
            </group>
            <group name="QA">
                <notifications>
                    <notificationType>Failed</notificationType>
                    <NotificationType>Success</NotificationType>
                    <NotificationType>Change</NotificationType>
                    <NotificationType>Fixed</NotificationType>
                </notifications>
            </group>
            <group name="BA">
                <notifications>
                    <notificationType>Change</notificationType>
                    <notificationType>Fixed</notificationType>
                </notifications>
            </group>
            <group name="PHITeam">
                <notifications>
                    <notificationType>Failed</notificationType>
                    <NotificationType>Success</NotificationType>
                    <NotificationType>Change</NotificationType>
                    <NotificationType>Fixed</NotificationType>
                </notifications>
            </group>
        </groups>
        <modifierNotificationTypes>
            <NotificationType>Failed</NotificationType>
            <NotificationType>Fixed</NotificationType>
            <NotificationType>Success</NotificationType>
            <NotificationType>Change</NotificationType>
            <NotificationType>Exception</NotificationType>
        </modifierNotificationTypes>
        <xslFiles>
            <file>xsl\header.xsl</file>
            <file>xsl\compile.xsl</file>
            <file>xsl\modifications.xsl</file>
        </xslFiles>
    </email>
</cb:config-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the buildmaster receiving all mails, and the modifiers also
below is a setup I use, and that one works great. It has less groups than you, but you'll get the idea.

```
<cb:define name="email_publisher">
<email from="CruiseControl@xyz.com" 
      mailhost="mailserver" 
      includeDetails="TRUE">

    <users>
        <user name="Ruben Willems" group="buildmaster" address="ruben.willems@whatever.com" /> 
    </users>

    <groups>
        <group name="buildmaster" >
            <notifications>
                <NotificationType>Exception</NotificationType>
            </notifications>                
        </group>
    </groups> 


    <converters>
        <ldapConverter domainName="FortKnox" ldapQueryField="displayName" />
    </converters> 

    <modifierNotificationTypes>
       <NotificationType>Failed</NotificationType>
       <NotificationType>Fixed</NotificationType>
    </modifierNotificationTypes>

</email>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I wanted the buildmaster to get all emails. However, I do not want development, QA, etc to receive the emails for Exception. I will run a test to see what happens when I specify 'Exception' for buildmaster. Maybe that will trigger something.

Comment: if buildmaster should get all the mails, include all types in the notifications element, and for the others the same, except the 'Exception' type, 
that should get the result you want

Comment: This is still an issue despite variations on this. Whenever the build has an exception, usually because there is a glitch connecting to the SVN server, emails get sent to everyone despite listing just Success, Failed, etc for the various groups and users. Thanks to those who have tried to offer tips here.